# Out of memory on a 28-byte allocation - Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, amazon-ec2, out-of-memory

So I have this app that connects to a mysql server running on ec2. The connection is being made, but when I'm pulling data, I'm getting this error:

```
05-19 22:15:21.988: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 724K, 3% free 37841K/38620K, paused 24ms, total 24ms
05-19 22:15:22.508: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 90K, 1% free 39780K/39936K, paused 4ms, total 4ms
05-19 22:15:23.228: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 121K, 1% free 41697K/41884K, paused 5ms, total 5ms
05-19 22:15:23.818: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 111K, 1% free 43625K/43800K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
05-19 22:15:24.378: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 162K, 1% free 45502K/45728K, paused 6ms, total 6ms
05-19 22:15:25.018: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10K, 1% free 47531K/47604K, paused 7ms, total 8ms
05-19 22:15:25.538: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 238K, 1% free 49333K/49636K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
05-19 22:15:26.178: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10K, 1% free 51363K/51436K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
05-19 22:15:26.808: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10K, 1% free 53395K/53468K, paused 10ms, total 10ms
05-19 22:15:27.328: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 8K, 1% free 55047K/55124K, paused 11ms, total 11ms
05-19 22:15:27.798: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 353K, 1% free 56734K/57152K, paused 12ms, total 12ms
05-19 22:15:28.438: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10K, 1% free 58767K/58840K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
05-19 22:15:29.168: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10K, 1% free 60799K/60872K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
05-19 22:15:29.848: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 10K, 1% free 62831K/62904K, paused 14ms, total 14ms
05-19 22:15:30.268: I/dalvikvm-heap(1947): Clamp target GC heap from 64.889MB to 64.000MB
05-19 22:15:30.268: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 522K, 1% free 64346K/64936K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
05-19 22:15:30.618: I/dalvikvm-heap(1947): Clamp target GC heap from 65.981MB to 64.000MB
05-19 22:15:30.618: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 5K, 1% free 65463K/65536K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
05-19 22:15:30.618: I/dalvikvm-heap(1947): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 16-byte allocation
05-19 22:15:30.638: I/dalvikvm-heap(1947): Clamp target GC heap from 65.972MB to 64.000MB
05-19 22:15:30.638: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 71K, 1% free 65392K/65536K, paused 18ms, total 19ms
05-19 22:15:30.648: I/dalvikvm-heap(1947): Clamp target GC heap from 65.980MB to 64.000MB
05-19 22:15:30.648: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 65400K/65536K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
05-19 22:15:30.678: I/dalvikvm-heap(1947): Clamp target GC heap from 65.980MB to 64.000MB
05-19 22:15:30.678: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 1% free 65400K/65536K, paused 26ms, total 26ms
05-19 22:15:30.708: I/dalvikvm-heap(1947): Clamp target GC heap from 65.981MB to 64.000MB
05-19 22:15:30.708: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 1% free 65400K/65536K, paused 27ms, total 27ms
05-19 22:15:30.708: I/dalvikvm-heap(1947): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 13-byte allocation
05-19 22:15:30.728: I/dalvikvm-heap(1947): Clamp target GC heap from 65.980MB to 64.000MB
05-19 22:15:30.728: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed <1K, 1% free 65399K/65536K, paused 21ms, total 21ms
05-19 22:15:30.738: I/dalvikvm-heap(1947): Clamp target GC heap from 65.981MB to 64.000MB
05-19 22:15:30.738: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 1% free 65399K/65536K, paused 13ms, total 13ms
05-19 22:15:30.738: I/dalvikvm-heap(1947): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 17-byte allocation
05-19 22:15:30.758: I/dalvikvm-heap(1947): Clamp target GC heap from 65.981MB to 64.000MB
05-19 22:15:30.758: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 0K, 1% free 65399K/65536K, paused 19ms, total 19ms
05-19 22:15:30.758: E/dalvikvm-heap(1947): Out of memory on a 17-byte allocation.
05-19 22:15:30.758: I/dalvikvm(1947): "Thread-84" prio=5 tid=11 RUNNABLE JIT
05-19 22:15:30.758: I/dalvikvm(1947):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb3033668 self=0xb9085ad0
05-19 22:15:30.758: I/dalvikvm(1947):   | sysTid=1960 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1190557824
05-19 22:15:30.758: I/dalvikvm(1947):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=33 stm=17 core=0
05-19 22:15:30.758: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:~2267)
05-19 22:15:30.758: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:2044)
05-19 22:15:30.758: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3549)
05-19 22:15:30.758: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:489)
05-19 22:15:30.758: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3240)
05-19 22:15:30.758: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2411)
05-19 22:15:30.768: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2834)
05-19 22:15:30.768: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2832)
05-19 22:15:30.768: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2781)
05-19 22:15:30.768: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1569)
05-19 22:15:30.768: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.example.hotwaterheater.AWSconnect.run(AWSconnect.java:94)
05-19 22:15:30.768: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-19 22:15:30.778: I/dalvikvm-heap(1947): Clamp target GC heap from 65.981MB to 64.000MB
05-19 22:15:30.778: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 1% free 65399K/65536K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
05-19 22:15:30.778: I/dalvikvm-heap(1947): Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 28-byte allocation
05-19 22:15:30.798: I/dalvikvm-heap(1947): Clamp target GC heap from 65.981MB to 64.000MB
05-19 22:15:30.798: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 0K, 1% free 65399K/65536K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
05-19 22:15:30.798: E/dalvikvm-heap(1947): Out of memory on a 28-byte allocation.
05-19 22:15:30.798: I/dalvikvm(1947): "Thread-84" prio=5 tid=11 RUNNABLE JIT
05-19 22:15:30.798: I/dalvikvm(1947):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb3033668 self=0xb9085ad0
05-19 22:15:30.798: I/dalvikvm(1947):   | sysTid=1960 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=-1190557824
05-19 22:15:30.798: I/dalvikvm(1947):   | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=35 stm=18 core=0
05-19 22:15:30.808: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:~2267)
05-19 22:15:30.808: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:2044)
05-19 22:15:30.808: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3549)
05-19 22:15:30.808: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:489)
05-19 22:15:30.808: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3240)
05-19 22:15:30.808: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2411)
05-19 22:15:30.808: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2834)
05-19 22:15:30.808: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2832)
05-19 22:15:30.808: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2781)
05-19 22:15:30.808: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeQuery(StatementImpl.java:1569)
05-19 22:15:30.808: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at com.example.hotwaterheater.AWSconnect.run(AWSconnect.java:94)
05-19 22:15:30.808: I/dalvikvm(1947):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
05-19 22:15:30.808: W/dalvikvm(1947): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0d09b20)
05-19 22:15:30.828: D/dalvikvm(1947): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 28074K, 4% free 37325K/38528K, paused 28ms, total 28ms
05-19 22:15:30.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1947): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-84
05-19 22:15:30.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1947): Process: com.example.hotwaterheater, PID: 1947
05-19 22:15:30.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1947): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: [memory exhausted]
05-19 22:15:30.828: E/AndroidRuntime(1947):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm assuming it probably has to do with the query string I'm using to pull the data, as I've limited the amount of data I'm pulling in to next to nothing and I'm still getting this error.
Here's the actual code:

```
java.sql.Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://<correctIP>:3306/test","   <user>","<password>");
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e1) {
            Log.d("TAG","Cannot Connect to server");
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "connected");
        try {
            Log.d(TAG, "just after connection");
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            String year = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
            int m = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
            String month = String.valueOf(m);
            if(month.length() == 1){
                month = "0" + month;
            }
            String day = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
            if(day.length() == 1){
                day = "0" + day;
            }
            String hour = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR));
            if(hour.length() == 1){
                hour = "0" + hour;
            }
            String minute = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
            if(minute.length() == 1){
                minute = "0" + minute;
            }
            String second = String.valueOf(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
            if(second.length() == 1){
                second = "0" + second;
            }
            String currDateTime = year + "-" + month + "-" + day + " " + hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;

            myHeater = HeaterSingleton.getInstance();
            String savedDate = myHeater.getLastDate();
            String savedYear, savedMonth, savedDay, savedHour;

            Log.d(TAG, "got currDate");

            //if this is the first time it's been opened.
            if(savedDate.equals("") || savedDate.equals(null)){
                myHeater.setLastDate("'2014-05-17 04:35:05'");
                savedDate = myHeater.getLastDate();
                savedYear = savedDate.substring(0,4);
                savedMonth = savedDate.substring(5,7);
                savedDay = savedDate.substring(8,10);
                savedHour = savedDate.substring(11,13);
                myHeater.setCurrYear(savedYear);
                myHeater.setCurrMonth(savedMonth);
                myHeater.setCurrDay(savedDay);
                myHeater.setCurrHour(savedHour);
            }else{
                savedYear = savedDate.substring(0,4);
                savedMonth = savedDate.substring(5,7);
                savedDay = savedDate.substring(8,10);
                savedHour = savedDate.substring(11,13);
            }

            Log.d(TAG, "just before select");
            java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            Log.d(TAG, "statement made");
            java.sql.ResultSet table = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM heater WHERE time >= " + savedDate);
            Log.d(TAG, "connected");
            int count = 0;
            Log.d(TAG, "pre-amazon setup done");
```

When I run it, it will make it through to the "statement made" log statement and then go no further, other than to give me the memory error. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't mind adding more code if necessary.

Comment: I suggest you log the query, then check how many results you get when running it elsewhere. I'd also *strongly* recommend that you use parameterized queries instead of building the value into the SQL itself, and ideally use a parameter of an appropriate date type instead of all this string manipulation.

Comment: Alright, I'd like to try all of that, but I'm not very sure how to do any of that. I'm a bit of a beginner. Are there any sites/links/other solutions that you might know of/be able to direct me to?

Comment: I'd start with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html. Do you really want to make your database publicly available like this though? I'd consider putting it behind a rather more focused web service.